# Azure SQL Server Database security not considering the System current IP

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-security

I understand that Microsoft Azure is very secure and the Azure SQL Server as well. However, the question is bit scenario based:

I'm accessing Azure SQL Server DB using SSMS, which is asking me to login using SQL Server authentication.

In Azure DB firewall security setting when I'm trying to add my current PC IP address ( which is Dynamic in nature ),its not adding.However, its actually considering my ISP provided IP address. The questions are: why its not allowing me to add my current IP address? Should not there be a security issue, if its considering my ISP IP ( which I can found "what is my IP") ? How and what level of security Microsoft is providing in this case? Is not it that, if someone will get my SQL Server credential they will go inside my SQL Sever in Azure?

OR

is it like that, the HOST/Computer name and IP address (which got via What is my IP) should be matched then the SQL Server credential will work? - Which is kind of more secure.

Hope I have explained this correctly.This is just to get more clarification not to compare.

I understand that, I think, I should have static IP. But, the local IP is dynamic.

Thanks.

Comment: Your address from SQL Server's point of view is your public IP address, not your local address. The local address only means something within your local area network. It is not routable from the internet.

Comment: If you have an internet connection that uses dynamic IP addressing and you have trouble getting through the firewall, try one of the following solutions: 1. Ask your internet service provider for the IP address range that's assigned to your client computers that access the server. Add that IP address range as an IP firewall rule. 2.  Get static IP addressing instead for your client computers. Add the
   IP addresses as IP firewall rules.

Comment: Ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#troubleshoot-the-database-firewall

Answer (score 0):

It is the IP address assigned by your ISP what Azure SQL Database firewall can "see". That is the one you need to add as firewall rule. The private IP address your computer is using on your local network cannot be "seen" by Azure SQL database firewall.

Azure SQL Database security is more than just a firewall rule. All data in transit coming from any Azure SQL Database or going to any Azure SQL Database is encrypted. Azure SQL Database does not allow non-encrypted connections. All this is happening on TCP port 1433. You cannot communicate to Azure SQL Database on a different port.

When a client first attempts a connection to SQL Azure Database, it sends an initial connection request. Consider this a "pre-pre-connection" request. At this point the client does not know if SSL/Encryption is required and waits an answer from SQL Azure to determine if SSL is indeed required throughout the session (not just the login sequence, the entire connection session). A bit is set on the response indicating so. Then the client library disconnects and reconnects armed with this information.

When you set Encrypt to true you avoid the "pre-pre-connection", and you are preventing any proxy from turning off the encryption bit on the client side of the proxy, this way attacks like man-in-the-middle attack are avoided.

When secure connections are needed, it is recommended to enable "Encrypt connection" setting on SSMS.

In addition to all this, when you create a new database on Azure SQL Database data at rest is encrypted. Transparent Data Encryption is enabled by deafult.